# Number of solutions of equation $ a ^ x = 2016x$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Determine how many solutions $x \in \mathbb{R}$, depending on parameter $a > 0$, has this equation got:
$ a ^ x = 2016x$

Could you give me any ideas how to start this? I'm sure this problem needs to be solved somehow using derivatives, I obviously know how to calculate it, but I don't have got any idea how to use it.

Comment: Put $f(x)=a^x-2016x$, $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<0$ (at least for $a<2016$). Now use first derivative to show that the function is decreasing in the whole real set.

Comment: @N74 "decreasing in the whole real set" Untrue if $a>1$.

Answer (score 5):

Think of the two sides of the equation as functions on the $(x,y)$ plane, and look at where they cross. $y=2016x$ is a steeply increasing straight line through the origin, whereas $y=a^x$ depends on $a$. For $0 < a <1$ it is strictly decreasing and never $0$, it is $1$ at $x=0$ and then goes down asymptotically, so that we always have exactly one crossing. For $a=1$ we have the constant function $1$, hence still one crossing. For $a > 1$, the function $y=a^x$ is strictly increasing and never $0$, it is $1$ at $x=0$ and then goes up towards infinity. Any exponential grows faster than any polynomial, hence in the end your $a^x$ will have a greater value than $2016x$, for $x$ big enough. If $a$ is really big, then the exponential does not even touch the line $y=2016x$ and shoots up to infinity before crossing it. If it has a certain critical value, it just touches the line and then grows faster. And underneath this critical value of $a$, you have two intersections.

All you have to do is to find the critical value of $a$, and as you said this has to do with derivatives: since indeed, when two (differentiable) graphs are tangent, they have the same derivative at that point. So, by differentiating,  look for the value of $a$ where the two functions $y=a^x$ and $y=2016x$ have the same value and the same derivative at some point. This will give you the situation of just one common point, all higher values of $a$ give you no intersection, all smaller values give you two intersections.

[added]
To find the "critical" value of $a$, consider the system of equations given by your equality and its derivative, namely

$ (1) \quad a^x = 2016x \\ (2)  \quad  \log{(a)} \cdot a^x = 2016$

Note that $\log{}$ refers to the logarithm with basis $e$. By inserting $(1)$ into $(2)$, you obtain $x=\frac{1}{\log{(a)}}$ (note that we assumed that $a>1$, so this is well-defined). By reinserting this into $(1)$ you get $a^{\frac{1}{\log{(a)}}}=e^{\frac{\log{(a)}}{\log{(a)}}}=e=\frac{2016}{\log{(a)}}$, hence $a=e^\frac{2016}{e}$ is your critical value.

Comment: I am sorry but your answer doesn't consider (apparently, because it is rather hard to follow your argumentation) the case $0<a<1$ giving as well one intersection point.

Comment: Sure, you're right, I just considered $a > 1$. Well, as you said, for $0 < a  \le 1$, one always gets exactly one solution. I will edit it. As for the answer, I tried to keep intuitive because I don't know what tools can be used, but apparently it was not so intuitive after all ;)

Comment: Anyhow, my problem is not with the beginning of your geometrical interpretation (I quite agree) but with its end where the usefulness/effectiveness of comparing derivatives looks me very doubtful.

Comment: It is just to find the "critical" value for $a$ in an easy way. Maybe now it is clearer. Thanks for your comments, anyway.

Comment: Thank you A LOT for that! I guess I roughly understand that idea now. But could you give some more info about finding that critical point? I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I've added the explicit solution

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the general equation $a^x=bx$ and solve it:
$$1=bxa^{-x}$$
$$1=bxe^{-x\ln a}$$
$$\frac1b=xe^{-x\ln a}$$
$$-\frac{\ln a}b=(-x\ln a)e^{-x\ln a}$$
We note that the right-hand side has the form of the inverse of the Lambert W function, i.e. $ze^z$.
$$W\left(-\frac{\ln a}b\right)=-x\ln a$$
$$x=-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\ln a}b\right)}{\ln a}$$
The number of solutions to the equation $a^x=bx$ therefore depends on the argument of the W function, $k=-\frac{\ln a}b$.

- If $k<-\frac1e$ then the equation has no solution.
- If $-\frac1e<k<0$ then the equation has two solutions, corresponding to the two branches of the W function in this range.
- Else, the equation has a single solution.

Answer (score 0):

$\arctan 2016\approx 1.57030029509$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}-1.57030029509 \approx 0.0004960317$ then the line $y=2016x$ is almost vertical.

On the other hand $y=a^x$ is equal to $1$ for $a=1$, it is increasing for $a\gt 1$ and decreasing for $0\lt a\lt1$.

Hence there is an  intersection point, near in $\Bbb R^2$ to $(1,1)$ when $a$ is not too large and a second one because  the exponential must be greater than the line.

However when $a$ is large enough there is no solution.
Precisaly there are values $a$ and $x$ such that $a^x\ln a=2016$ in which case the line $y=2016x$ is tangent to the $y=a^x$ therefore for greater values of $a$ there is not solution.

Comment: For some values of $a$ there are two intersection points, for others none, for others one.

Comment: Here is a counterexample 2016^x=2016x has two solutions $x=1$ and $x=0.0004979...$